# Starting a service from a non-UI thread (Bluetooth)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, bluetooth

I've created a distinct thread in my app for the purposes of creating an RFCOMM socket to communicate with. However, I want the actual communication to be done in a service so it can persist across dumb things like orientation changes.

Something like this:

```
private class grabSocket extends Thread {
  private BluetoothSocket socket = null;
  public SocketRetriever(BluetoothDevice device) {
    socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID);
  }
}
```

How can I now pass this socket to a service? If I try to do it from within the thread, will the service outlive the thread, or will it just die as soon as the thread does?

Comment: Couldn't you just do this from the Service in the first place?  If not though, you could bind to the Service, then in your ServiceConnection callback method cast your IBinder interface to your Service's Binder implementation to get a reference to your Service, then call a method to set the socket on the Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Submersed mentioned, you can pass this socket to your service using binder.

> If I try to do it from within the thread, will the service outlive the thread, or will it just die as soon as the thread does?

If you start a service then it will work till you explicitly call `stopService` or `stopSelf`. If you bind to it, it will work till last client unbinds from it. So, service's lifecycle doesn't depend on thread's lifecycle.

Comment: Cool. If I use a Service, will I be able to spawn a thread from it to write to the Bluetooth socket?

Comment: Sure. By default Service works on the UI thread. You can spawn as many threads as you need.

Comment: I gave it a try. My threads (called from the Service) just die when the orientation changes. Any ideas?

Comment: why do you think they die? If you start a thread it will live till method 'run' returns no matter from where you start it either activity or service or whatever. threads have their own lifecycle.

Comment: Perhaps a thread isn't the best choice then. I need it to stay alive as long as the user keeps the Bluetooth connected so it can write. In fact, I don't even have a `run` method. :-(

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't worked with bluetooth yet so I don't know what's the best practice.. if you need some code to be executed on background then you need a thread and you should override method `run` then.